# PostgreSQL: Fast check whether all elements of an LTREE [] <@ LTREE[]

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, ltree

I have the following tables (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE groups
 ( id PRIMARY KEY, 
   path ltree,
   ... 
 );

CREATE TABLE items
 ( id bigserial, 
   path ltree,
   ... 
   PRIMARY KEY (id, path)
 );
```

For each item, there is a list of groups that the item belongs too. A group is represented by its full path. There may be up to 10M items, each item belongs to about 20 groups.

I need to design the following query. Given (a) a "parent" group and (b) a list of up to 10 additional groups, find those immediate descendants of the "parent" group that have at least one item in their subtree that is contained in each of the groups in the search criteria.

For example, given the parent group "NorthAmerica.USA" and additional groups ["CandyLovers.ChocolateLovers", "Athletes.Footballers"], then "NorthAmerica.USA.CA" is a result if it there exists an item like "George" that is in the groups like ["NorthAmerica.USA.CA.LosAngeles", "Athletes.Footballers", "CandyLovers.ChocolateLovers.ChocolateDonutLovers"]

I tried a few different ways to write queries, and they scale very poorly: take minutes to return result on a set of 1M items and 3-4 paths in the search criteria. For example:

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT *
    FROM groups
    WHERE path ~ CAST ('1.2.22' || '.*{1}' AS lquery)
          AND EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
           FROM
             (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT leaf_paths_sans_result_path.path) AS paths_of_a_match,
                     max(path_count) AS path_count
              FROM items,

                (SELECT path,
                   count(*) OVER() AS path_count
                 FROM (
                        VALUES (groups.path) , ('1.3'),('1.4')) t (path)) leaf_paths_sans_result_path
              WHERE 1 = 1
                    AND items.path <@ leaf_paths_sans_result_path.path
              GROUP BY id) items_by_id
           WHERE cardinality(paths_of_a_match) = path_count );
```

Results in the following:

```
     Index Scan using idx_groups__path__gist on groups  (cost=0.28..37013.74 rows=38 width=469) (actual time=11.735..322285.421 rows=950 loops=1)
       Index Cond: (path ~ '1.2.22.*{1}'::lquery)
       Filter: (SubPlan 1)
       Rows Removed by Filter: 3
       SubPlan 1
         ->  Subquery Scan on items_by_id  (cost=0.55..1809359.86 rows=3752 width=0) (actual time=338.162..338.162 rows=1 loops=953)
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.55..1809322.34 rows=3752 width=65) (actual time=338.159..338.159 rows=1 loops=953)
                     Group Key: ibt.id
                     Filter: (cardinality(array_agg(DISTINCT "*VALUES*".column1)) >= max(3))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 7845
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..1809228.54 rows=3752 width=65) (actual time=0.044..307.087 rows=20423 loops=953)
                           Join Filter: (ibt.path <@ "*VALUES*".column1)
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 651228
                           ->  Index Scan using idx_items__id on items  (cost=0.55..1752954.06 rows=1250543 width=193) (actual time=0.007..110.517 rows=223884 loops=953)
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=3 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=3 loops=213361141)
                                 ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=3 loops=953)
     Planning time: 3.151 ms
     Execution time: 322286.404 ms
    (18 rows)
```

I can change the data model as needed in order to optimize for this query. I am running PostgreSQL v9.5

Many thanks! Sorry for a messy question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the [ltree module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ltree.html)?  The following query avoids the intermediate `array_agg` arrays:

```
select  *
from    items i
join    groups g
on      i.groups = g.id
where   g.path ~ '1.2.22.*' and
        (
             i.path ~ '*.1.3.*' or
             i.path ~ '*.1.4.*'
        )
group by
        g.id
having  count(distinct
        case
        when i.path ~ '*.1.3.*' then 1
        when i.path ~ '*.1.4.*' then 2
        end) = 2
```

The `count` constructs asserts that both conditions are met, not just two rows that match the same pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much! I clearly see an idea I couldn't think of before: your clever use of `count`/`case`.

I am still struggling with one aspect of your solution. I think there's a typo in the join clause, I figure you meant
`on i.path = g.path`. (the id in `items` is item id, the id in `paths` is a path id). But if that's the case, then `where   g.path ~ ''1.2.22.*'` filters out all items in other paths,
  like '1.3.*' etc. and I get no data found. Thanks a lot again for you help and patience!